# Modify List.Contains behavior

Tags: c#, list, contains, icomparable, icomparer

I have a `List<MyObj>` with the `class MyObj : IComparable`. I wrote the method `CompareTo` in the `MyObj` class per the `IComparable` interface, but when I use the `List<MyObj>.Contains(myObjInstance)` it returns `false` when it should be `true`.

I'm not sure I'm understanding how I need to proceed to make sure the `List` uses my custom comparison method when calling then `Contains` function.

Here is my compareTo implementation:

```
    #region IComparable Members

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        MyObj myObj = (MyObj)obj;
        return String.Compare(this.Symbol, myObj.Symbol, true);
    }

    #endregion
```

Note the Symbol property is a string.

To clarify I've put a stopping point in that compareTo method and it doesn't even go in there.

Anyone has ever tried that?

Thanks.

Comment: Specifically the implementation of CompareTo

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The absolute easiest way to find out whether your CompareTo method is called is to set a breakpoint in it and hit F5 to run your program. But I believe that `List<T>.Contains` looks for the [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) interface for making the comparison.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) for `List<T>.Contains`, it uses either your implementation of `IEquatable` interface or `object.Equals`, that you can override as well.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try overriding the Equals method?

`List<T>`, according to reflector, uses `EqualityComparer<T>` to check for containment, and the default implementation (ObjectEqualityComparer) uses Equals for most normal objects.