# Foreach loop doesn't finish in c# with List<>

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I know it's very strange but I don't find another way to say it. Please see the image below
[image: count list]

[image]

The output is 1 and always it's the same!

I really don't understand what happend here. Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: Does `TodasMediciones` contain 4 of the same value?

Comment: What is the type of `Mediciones`? Why do you think the foreach loop doesn't finish? Use the debugger to step through the execution of the loop. In particular, see if the `if` condition triggers in each loop iteration.

Comment: output to the console a statement like "Loop Ended" at the end of the loop. That's the easiest way to test whether the loop ends or not.

Comment: `TodasMediciones` does not contain the same values.

Comment: Can you try moving i += 1; Console.WriteLine(i); outside the if to see how many times it loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple of observations on your `Modelo` and `Medicion` classes:

```
public class Modelo<T>
{
    // 1) note PROTECTED set on Id
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        ...
        // 2) comparison is based on Id
        return (this == obj || this.Id == specificOject.Id);
    }
    ...
}

public class Medicion : Modelo<Medicion> {...}
```

1. The `Id` member is defined as `protected set`.
2. The `Equals` method defines two objects as the same if the `Id` in both are the same.

Are you setting the `Id` of your `Medicion` objects anywhere? If not, they are likely to all be `0`.  If all the Ids are the same, this makes all your objects look the same (your equality definition is based on `Id`).

Therefore, `Mediciones.Contains` will always be `true` after the first object is added.  You don't provide any info on `Mediciones`, but I am assuming here that it is a standard `List` with no overrides.

Answer (score 0):

One of those intellisense dialogs is showing you TodasMediciones. The other is showing you Mediciones. These are not the same value.

Answer (score 0):

See [Modify List.Contains behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076350/modify-list-contains-behavior)

You're going to want to implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) in your `Medicion`.

Comment: Good call, but you'd think the default implementation would use a reference comparison, and therefore trigger the `if` condition all four times through the loop, for each of the four different objects in the list.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I'm pretty sure the default `List<T>` behavior when you `Add` an object is to copy it.

Comment: Well, copy the reference to the object. It doesn't do a deep copy. There are four objects he's adding from `TodasMediciones` to `Mediciones`. I'd think that the `Contains` would return false for each new item.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is your problem. The loop loops on TodasMediciones which is a List. The second debugger is on Mediciones. Both are different objects.

Comment: The second image just shows that the `Mediciones` isn't the same values than `TodasMediciones`

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm wrong. The problem (I don't know why) is `!Mediciones.Contains(m)`. The first time is false and in the next iterations is true.
I change method as follow

```
public virtual void AddMediciones(List<Medicion> TodasMediciones)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (Medicion m in TodasMediciones)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Mediciones.Contains(m));
                Console.WriteLine(m.Valor);
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
                if (!Mediciones.Contains(m))
                {
                    Mediciones.Add(m);
                }
            }
        }
```

Their output is:

```
False
1
-------------------------------------------
True
2
-------------------------------------------
True
3
-------------------------------------------
True
4
-------------------------------------------
```

Here is the Medicion definition:

```
public class Medicion : Modelo<Medicion>
    {
        public virtual DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal Valor { get; set; }
        public virtual Indicador Indicador { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And their parent definition

```
public class Modelo<T>
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        Modelo<T> specificOject = (Modelo<T>)obj;
        return (this == obj || this.Id == specificOject.Id);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode() ^ 5;
    }
}
```